# How to run a function as a child process in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, subprocess, fork

I have a function `dosomething()`  inside which am doing a `os.chroot()`. A process running chroot() cannot get out of chroot jail. So i want this `dosomething()` to run as a child process in the main program and i need to wait till the child process gets over . What is the simplest way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `multiprocess.Process`